# How do you create a many to many relationship using the code first approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to setup a basic optional many to many relationship between a Reptile model and a Tag model so that reptiles can have tags and tags can provide a list of reptiles.

I've tried a number of setups from other questions I've read, but I can't seem to get this relationship to work. This is the current setup I have:

Reptile model:

```
public class Reptile
{
    public int ReptileId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //...

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Tag Model:

```
public class Tag
{
public int TagId { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(30)]
public string Title { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Description { get; set; }

//...

public ICollection<Reptile> Reptiles { get; set; }
}
```

DB Context:

```
public class ReptizonDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Reptile> Reptiles { get; set; }

    public ReptizonDBContext()
        : base("ReptilesDBContext")
    {
    }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Reptile>().HasMany(r => r.Tags).WithMany(t => t.Reptiles);

       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   }
}
```

However, I get the following error when trying to run the site:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.ReptileTags_dbo.Tags_Tag_TagId' on table 'ReptileTags' may
>   cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>
> Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

How should I be creating this many to many relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in **OnModelCreating**

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

note: this delete CASCADE DELETES for all relationships

or use

```
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```